# type 'null' is not a subtype of type 'list dynamic ' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter

Please can anyone explain what's the issue with this! I am getting this error "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast"

&

"Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type"

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class AutoGenerate {
  AutoGenerate({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.results,
  });
  late final int status;
  late final String message;
  late final List<Results> results;
  
  AutoGenerate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    results = List.from(json['results']).map((e)=>Results.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['status'] = status;
    _data['message'] = message;
    _data['results'] = results.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Results {
  Results({
    required this.id,
    required this.category,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.type,
     this.image,
     this.video,
    required this.deliveryTime,
    required this.deliveryFund,
    required this.maximumFund,
    required this.progress,
    required this.startTime,
    required this.endTime,
     this.participants,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final Category category;
  late final String name;
  late final String description;
  late final int type;
  late final String? image;
  late final String? video;
  late final String deliveryTime;
  late final int deliveryFund;
  late final int maximumFund;
  late final int progress;
  late final String startTime;
  late final String endTime;
  late final List<Participants>? participants;
  late final String createdAt;
  late final String updatedAt;
  
  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    category = Category.fromJson(json['category']);
    name = json['name'];
    description = json['description'];
    type = json['type'];
    image = null;
    video = null;
    deliveryTime = json['delivery_time'];
    deliveryFund = json['delivery_fund'];
    maximumFund = json['maximum_fund'];
    progress = json['progress'];
    startTime = json['start_time'];
    endTime = json['end_time'];
    participants = null;
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['category'] = category.toJson();
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['description'] = description;
    _data['type'] = type;
    _data['image'] = image;
    _data['video'] = video;
    _data['delivery_time'] = deliveryTime;
    _data['delivery_fund'] = deliveryFund;
    _data['maximum_fund'] = maximumFund;
    _data['progress'] = progress;
    _data['start_time'] = startTime;
    _data['end_time'] = endTime;
    _data['participants'] = participants;
    _data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    _data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Category {
  Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final String description;
  
  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    description = json['description'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['description'] = description;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Participants {
  Participants({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
    required this.avatar,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final String phone;
  late final String avatar;
  
  Participants.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['phone'] = phone;
    _data['avatar'] = avatar;
    return _data;
  }
}

class JobsListView extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Results> result = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Results>>(
      future: _fetchJobs(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Results>? data = snapshot.data;
          return _jobsListView(data);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List<Results>> _fetchJobs() async {

    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/dummy.json');
    final productData = await json.decode(response);
    var list = productData['result'] as List<dynamic>;
    if (productData.statusCode == 200) {
      return productData.map((job) =>  Results.fromJson(job)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load jobs from API');
    }
  

  
     
    
  }

  ListView _jobsListView(data) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _tile(data[index].name, data[index].description, data[index].progress, data[index].category);
        });
  }
  Card _tile(String name, String description, String description2,String category) => Card(
          child: Text(name),
                      
        
        
      );
}
```

flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-arm, locale en-DE) • Flutter version 2.5.2 at /Users/almamun/Documents/developer/flutter • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git • Framework revision 3595343e20 (3 weeks ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700 • Engine revision 6ac856380f • Dart version 2.14.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0) • Android SDK at /Users/almamun/Library/Android/sdk • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0 • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189) • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer • Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A233 ✗ CocoaPods not installed. CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side. Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS. For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3) • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents • Flutter plugin can be installed from:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter • Dart plugin can be installed from:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2) • VS Code at /Users/almamun/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents • Flutter extension can be installed from:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available) • sdk gphone arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator) • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.81

Comment: error is in this Line
`var list = productData['result'] as List<dynamic>;`
make sure your data is not null or add condition

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a null value for a field with a list data type (maybe `results` field) in the response of your API call. The first error causes the control to be passed to the else statement of the `_fetchJobs()` method, and then you return no value there. That's why you have the second error.